# "I didn't need to" or "I needn't have"

Tags: modal-verbs

Which on is grammatically correct?

> - I didn't need to say anything. So I kept quiet.
> - I needn't have said anything. So I kept quiet.

If both are correct, What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: I don't know that it's a difference in meaning but I don't think Americans regularly use "needn't".

Comment: Any difference is too subtle for me - although you kept *quiet* rather than *quite*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I didn't need to say anything. So I kept quiet.
2. I needn't/need not have said anything. So I kept quiet.

The former statement is grammatical, whereas the latter isn't so.

The former means it was not necessary to say anything, so l kept quiet.

The latter means that although you said something, it wasn't necessary. The use of the sentence "So I kept quiet" is nonsensical as you said something.